# OpenCVのカメラアクセスについて: OpenCV: not authorized to capture video (status 0), requesting

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opencv

PCにカメラを2台接続し、C++、OpenCVを使って、それぞれから取得した映像をパノラマ合成したいと思っています。

下記サイトなどを参考にコードを作成しました。

- [OpenCV Stitching Module によるパノラマ画像合成の解説【ざっくり】 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/itoshogo3/items/7a3279668b24008a3761)
- [OpenCVによるUSBカメラ画像の取得 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/vs4sh/items/4a9ce178f1b2fd26ea30)

ビルドは通りましたが、コンソールログによると、カメラアクセス許可の部分で問題が発生しているようで、実行ができません。

Info.plistを作成し、NSCameraUsageDescriptionについては明示しており、
該当プロジェクトにもアタッチされていることを確認していますが、エラーが解消されません。

解決方法やその他試した方がいいことがあれば、ご教示いただきたいです。

**＜使用しているソフトウェアバージョン＞**

- macOS 10.14.6
- Xcode 11.3.1
- OpenCV 4.4.0

**＜コンソールログ＞**

```
 OpenCV: not authorized to capture video (status 0), requesting...
 
 [access] This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.
```

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/300900

Answer (score 0):

Qiitaの　[iOSカメラのアクセス許可](https://qiita.com/mczkzk/items/cd7ec80ef9071a018f19)　の記事が参考になりませんか？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。ただ、info.plistには、Privacy - Camera Usage Descriptionをすでに追加している状態です。

Comment: "利用目的の記載なしに、プライバシーにかかわるデータにアクセスしようとしたから"というエラーメッセージが出ているのですから、何か記述に問題があるのでしょう。
https://answers.unity.com/questions/1275836/camera-usage-description-localization.html　とかは、ご覧になりましたか？

Comment: そちらも試してみましたが、解決しませんでした。